# weak derivative of Lipschitz function is Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

In [Krylov's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540709138), he asserts that "the generalized derivative $u_x$ of a function $u$ continuous in $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ does not exceed a constant $N_1$ almost everywhere if and only if the function $u$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition in $\Omega$ with the same constant". Here he requires a generalized derivative must be **Borel measurable** as follows:

[image]

I knew that a Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and is differentiable Lebesgue almost everywhere. But usually $W^{1,\infty}$ means Lebesuge measurable weak derivatives.

Could you suggest any reference which shows a Lipschitz function has a Borel measurable weak derivative?

I guess one can show it by using a weak convergence argument and the fact that $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{B}(\Omega), \mathcal{L}_n)$ is a Hilbert space, where $\mathcal{L}_n$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
But I felt that this should be a fairly standard result and must have been shown somewhere.

Comment: I don't know a reference, but one can show that if $v$ is Lipschitz, then finite differences of the form $g^i_\delta (x): = [v(x+\delta l_i)-v(x)]/\delta$ converge point-wise almost everywhere as $\delta \to 0$, to a limit $g^i$ (which is automatically measurable as the limit of measurable functions). Given this, it is then also not hard to see that $g^i = v_{(l_i)}$.

Comment: @Sam May you explain more why $g^i=v_{(l_i)}$ since in general an a.e. differentiable continuous function doesn't imply it is weakly differentiable.

Comment: Take some compactly supported test function $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. Then for sufficiently small $\delta>0$ (depending on the distance of the support of $\phi$ to the boundary of $\Omega$), we obtain $\int_\Omega g^i_\delta(x) \phi(x) \, dx = \int_\Omega v(x)\left[ \phi(x-\delta l_i)-\phi(x) \right]/\delta\, dx$. Taking $\delta \to 0$, you find $\int_\Omega g^i(x) \phi(x) \, dx = - \int_\Omega v(x)\phi_{(l_i)}\, dx$, from which it follows that $g^i$ is the weak derivative of $v$. (To be able to take the limit on the left, we use dominated convergence.)

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your help.